# If Array.append has not mutable arguments partially applied then the lambda can be removed

Tags: arrays, lambda, f#

I have Array of Array of strings. I need to flatten them and I use:

```
Array.fold (fun acc el -> Array.append acc el) [||] arr2d
```

Lint says me that:

> "If Array.append has not mutable arguments partially applied then the
>   lambda can be removed"

What does it mean? How can I remove lambda?

Comment: As an aside the code can be shortened : `Array.collect id arr2d`

Comment: Can be further shortened to `Array.concat arr2d`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any lambda function in that form `(fun x -> f x)` can be expressed as `f`. Holding immutable condition.

In your code you have `fun acc el -> Array.append acc el` which has the same type and does the same as `Array.append`, so you can shorten it to:

```
Array.fold Array.append [||] arr2d
```

Comment: Haskell guys call that transformation [eta reduction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793843/what-does-eta-reduce-mean-in-the-context-of-hlint).

Comment: @scrwtp Not just Haskell guys, this is [the standard lambda-calculus name for it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: yes, but only Haskell guys call it that way in the open ;)

Comment: @scrwtp Counter-example: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/old_caml_site/FAQ/FAQ_EXPERT-eng.html :)