# How function reduction in Haskell works?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Why it's possible to reduce function in Haskell:

```
calculate :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
calculate a b = f 1 a b
  where
     f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
     f a b c = a + b
```

into something:

```
calculate :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
calculate = f 1
  where
     f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
     f a b c = a + b
```

I just need some guidance, any resources where I can find the answer and read more about it would be really helpful.

Comment: Yes, this is *eta conversion*: https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Haskell there are *no* functions that take more than one parameter. All functions take *exactly* one parameter.

So if you have a function like `add :: Int -> Int -> Int`, then this is actually short for `add :: Int -> (Int -> Int)`.

Why are the brackets important? Because they show how this concept works. If we have this function `add`, then we can make a function application with for example `14`, then we construct a *new* function, like:

```
add14 :: Int -> Int
add14 = add 14
```

so that means that we now have a function that takes again *one* parameter (here an `Int`), and now it will produce another `Int`, it does that by adding 14 to it, so `add14 25` will result in `39`.

If you write `add 14 25`, this thus is *not* a function application with two parameters, what you actually wrote is:

```
-- add 14 25 is equivalent to
(add 14) 25
```

You thus first make a call with `14`, and the you make a call with the function that comes out of this, and `25` as the parameter.

Why is this important? Because it means that if you thus write

```
calculate = f 1
```

it means that your `f 1`, constructs a function, a function with signature `Int -> (Int -> Int)`. Creating parameters in the head of `calculate`, and adding these to the end of `f 1`, thus makes no sense: you already constructed a function that takes such parameters anyway. So it only introduces noise.

In *lambda calculus*, the rewrite rule where one rewrites *λ x . f x* to just *f* is (and vice versa) is called [*η-conversion* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-conversion). In Haskell it comes down to rewriting:

```
f x = g x
```

to:

```
f = g
```

Operators are no different. In fact if you write `a + b` in Haskell, you wrote `(+) a b`, with `(+)` a function, or more verbose `((+) a) b`.

The `f` in the where clause:

```
f a b c = a + b
```

can for example get converted to:

```
f = (.) ((.) const) (+)
```

Comment: Really appreciate for your detailed answer, it couldn't have been any simpler explained when that :)

Comment: It's probably helpful to note as well that a definition like `foo a b = a + b` is really just syntactic sugar for `foo = \a -> \b -> a + b`: just a named assigned to an otherwise anonymous function defined by a lambda expression.

Comment: @chepner: good idea! I've added this at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It's called [eta](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion) [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion).

You might also think about it in terms of partial application.

```
> calculate :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
> f :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
> (f 1) :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
```

Similar question - [What does eta reduce mean in the context of HLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793843/what-does-eta-reduce-mean-in-the-context-of-hlint)